# Get correct ID from the database using multiple tables

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

I have this SQL query to get all the blog posts that are in the specific category:

```
SELECT * FROM blogposts AS bp, blogpost_categories AS bpc
WHERE bpc.id_category = '3'
AND bpc.id_blogpost = bp.id
ORDER BY bp.date_published DESC
```

The problem is that when I'll get the ID number for the blog post I'm getting the categories ID number, which is wrong.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: U r selecting all the columns right? Then what do you mean by 'am getting categories id number' ?

Comment: The columns are right, yes. I have double checked it numerous times

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!).

Comment: Then the old method is kicking even today because it works perfectly in other SQL querys I use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify which ID you want (f.e. `bp.id` or `bpc.id`.)  And consider a `join` to clarify the query:

```
SELECT  bp.id as BlogPostId
,       bpc.id as CategoryId
FROM    blogposts AS bp
JOIN    blogpost_categories AS bpc
ON      bpc.id_blogpost = bp.id
WHERE   bpc.id_category = '3'
```

Comment: Thanks but this SQL query will not print the information about the blog post. Only the categories for the blog post. I am using this SQL query in multiple files using a include so if I'm change `BlogPostId` to just `id` it will not work either. **EDIT** Nevermind! I saw that you used specific data in the SELECT ( `bp.id`) and not wildcard. Many thanks!